# Posix Utilities Missing?

Tags: linux, posix

I always assumed anything that was defined in the posix standard would be on most commons Linux distributions.

Yet when I looked up what utilities are standard in the posix standard I found [this page with a long list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html).

After trying some that I hadn't heard much about I quickly noticed many don't seem to be installed on my system.

Perhaps the utilities are just named differently? For example I don't have `c99` on my system but I do have `cc` which I assume can compile as `c99`.

Other utilities I tried but don't seem to be on my system:

- `what`
- `uux`
- `qalter`
- `renice`
- `sact`

I've only tried a handful of commands that looked unfamiliar but I'm guessing many more aren't on my system.

Are these optional utilities?

Comment: [`qalter`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/qalter.html) is marked optional and obsolescent. You could've gathered as much by _clicking_ through the links from that list. Also, since you're not telling the name of your system, I assume that it's something very secret and special, and consequently no conclusion can be drawn from it about Linux distros in general (FWIW, I haven't yet seen a non-embedded Linux system without `renice`).

Comment: If you really want an example of POSIX utility not present by default on most linux distros, it's [`ed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), the "standard" editor.

Comment: You should check what the codes, like `[UU]` and `[OB]` etc., means (in the description of the utilities, these are links that gives you their meaning). Some of these feature tags are used to describe optional (or in the case of `[OB]`, obsolete) components of a POSIX system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, many of them are optional:

- [`what`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/what.html) and [`sact`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sact.html) are part of SCCS (an old VCS, part of the XSI Development Utilities option in POSIX)
- [`uux`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uux.html) is part of UUCP ([optional](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#UU) in POSIX, still available in many distributions, *e.g.* [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/uucp))
- [`qalter`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/qalter.html) is part of the [Batch Environment Services](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap03.html#tag_19), an optional part of POSIX

[`renice`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/renice.html) should be present on most systems; in Debian it’s part of [`bsdutils`](https://tracker.debian.org/bsdutils), which is one of the core packages which are always supposed to be present. As far as POSIX is concerned, `renice` was optional in Issue 6, but it’s part of Base in Issue 7.

At least on some distributions (Debian 10, Fedora 31), installing GCC results in a `c99` command being made available.

If you’re aiming for [conformance](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_01_03), you’ll need to ensure the required packages are installed, for Base and any Options you’re claiming. The “tags” ([UU], [XSI], [BE] etc.) next to command names link to information about the requirements they correspond to.

Comment: It's worth _explicitly stating_ that conformance necessitates installing the appropriate packages.

Comment: I would hope anyone interested in conformance would read the corresponding chapter, but yes, it doesn’t hurt to be explicit here.

Comment: Since SCCS ist OpenSource since December 2006, there is no problem to include this development utility. A portable and maintained version is part of the schilytools.

Comment: I find that it's one of the most common errors in this area.  People erroneously assume that their default-installed Linux-based operating system must be conformant.

Comment: Linux is not POSIX and most current Linux distros have the problem that they act like commercial platforms that like to sell each feature separately. If Linux did deliver the typical UNIX set from the late 1980s by default, less people did have problems and since disk space has become cheep, including that on the filesystem is not a real problem that eats up expensive space.